# How to fix ‘the label's position in the frames”

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I put the two brown labels into the blue frame and green frame respectively?

I can put the pink label in the yellow frame but other two brown labels are not in the position where I want to put.

```py
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('frame test')
window.geometry('600x450')

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='In the left side of window', bg='red',
                  fg='white').pack(side='left')

frameShow = tk.Frame(window, bg='yellow', width=100,height=50)
frameShow.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(frameShow, text='In the left side of yellow frame',
                  bg='pink').pack(side='left')

subFramel = tk.Frame(frameShow, bg='green', width=200,height=200).pack()

label3 = tk.Label(subFramel, text='Inside the green frame',
                  bg='brown', fg='white').pack(side='right')

subFrame2 = tk.Frame(frameShow, bg='blue',
                     width=180,height=200).pack(side='left')

label3 = tk.Label(subFrame2, text='Inside the blue frame',
                  bg='brown', fg='white').pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you are setting your variable as `subFrame=tk.Frame(...).pack()` when it should be `subFrame=tk.Frame(...)` The code below should work. I included borderwidth=2 so you can see the frame color, since the frame is automatically shrink to the frame contents.

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('frame test')
window.geometry('600x450')

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='In the left side of window', bg='red', fg='white')
label1.pack(side='left')

frameShow = tk.Frame(window, bg='yellow', width=100,height=50)
frameShow.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(frameShow, text='In the left side of yellow frame', bg='pink')
label2.pack(side='left')

subFramel = tk.Frame(frameShow, bg='green', width=200,height=200, borderwidth=2)
subFramel.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(subFramel, text='Inside the green frame', bg='brown', fg='white')
label3.pack(side='right')

subFrame2 = tk.Frame(frameShow, bg='blue', width=180,height=200, borderwidth=2)
subFrame2.pack(side='left')

label3 = tk.Label(subFrame2, text='Inside the blue frame',bg='brown', fg='white', borderwidth=2)
label3.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works directly that is what I want.
But I want to know what is different between `.pack()` in the end of the line and created in the next line such as `label2.pack(side='left')`?

Comment: When you set the variable as `label2=tk.Label()`, then the label2 variable is a Label object. On the other hand, if you set the variable `label2=tk.Label().pack()`, then the label2 variable will be the output of the pack method, which is None. You can check by printing the type of your variable. `print(type(label2))`

Answer (score -1):

You can just make things simpler and use:

```
label2.place(x = {positionInPixels), y = {positionInPixels))
```

Trial and error process, but a lot simpler. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could use, instead of `.pack()` for your frames, `.grid()` which I think makes it a bit easier to work with. It does basically the same as pack but you specify where you want your frame to go in a grid. You specify the column for each frame to occupy (`column=0, row=0`) and how many of each it should take up (`rowspan=2` for the blank and yellow frames).

After this you simply `.pack("left")` your labels into the frames you want.

(`.pack_propagate(False)` must be called on frames to stop them shrinking when you put the label in.)

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Frame Test')
window.geometry('600x600')

blank_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=200,height=600)
blank_frame.pack_propagate(False) 
blank_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=2)

yellow_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg='yellow', width=200,height=600)
yellow_frame.pack_propagate(False) # stops label shrinking when it gets a label in it
yellow_frame.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2)

green_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg='green', width=200,height=300)
green_frame.pack_propagate(False)
green_frame.grid(column=2, row=0)

blue_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg='blue', width=200,height=300)
blue_frame.pack_propagate(False)
blue_frame.grid(column=2, row=1)


yellow_label = tk.Label(yellow_frame, text='In the left side of yellow frame',  bg='pink')
yellow_label.pack(side='left')

green_label = tk.Label(green_frame, text='Inside the green frame',  bg='brown')
green_label.pack(side='left')

green_label = tk.Label(blue_frame, text='Inside the blue frame',  bg='brown')
green_label.pack(side='left')

left_side_label = tk.Label(blank_frame, text='In the left side of the window',  bg='red')
left_side_label.pack(side='left')

window.mainloop()
```